# How to know marker latitude and longitude position and draw a polyline

Tags: android, google-maps, latitude-longitude

I am developing an android google map application, that is showing current location on map starting.

[image]

I have an search bar in the application, when user enter any area name, then the second marker will be placed on that location.

[image]

Now my problem is, how to get second marker longitude and latitude position and make a route between the two markers.

my MainActivity.java code as follows:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    public void onMapSearch(View view) {
        EditText locationSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        String location = locationSearch.getText().toString();
        List<Address> addressList = null;

        if (location != null || !location.equals("")) {
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
            try {
                addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location, 1);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Address address = addressList.get(0);
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Marker"));
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(27.746974, 85.301582);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Kathmandu, Nepal"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        // Enable MyLocation Button in the Map
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Please Help me.

Comment: Check solution here, if you want to draw a path between your locations

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26112591/draw-path-between-two-points-on-the-map-google-maps-using-eclipse/26113218#26113218

Comment: can you please elaborate your answer..

Comment: i don't have second marker latitude and longitude position, how to fetch these values from my code..

Comment: Well you can get the lat lng of that position(2nd marker and store them in arraylist)

Comment: how to get and store lng lat in arraylist, can u give me a piece of code

Comment: arraylist_lat_lon.add(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location
                    .getLongitude()));

Comment: sorry..i couldn't get it

Answer (score 0):

In your program you have used the code to get the LatLng of the second marker.

```
LatLng latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Marker"));
```

To make a polyline, refer to this link. By the this question has already been answered.

https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/google-maps-distance-calculator-google-maps-api/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38583015/how-to-calculate-distance-and-duration-for-multiple-locations-using-distance-mat/38583719#38583719

Comment: i have DirectionsJSONParser.java file, that includes your code.

Answer (score 0):

Set `Google Places API` for search `EdiText`. Get the value from that and pass it as address..

Here is the code(`address` denoting `strAddress` here)

```
    List<Address> address = null;
    Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext());
    try {
        address = coder.getFromLocationName(strAddress, 1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (address != null) {
        Address location = address.get(0);
        double lat = location.getLatitude();
        double log = location.getLongitude();
    }
```